# panel to Imagelist in C#

Tags: c#

Hello friends i want to create new bitmap image of panel and want to store it in the imagelist  and when the controls in the panel gets changed i want the image with different name and to be added to the image list and here goes my code for this.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
     var listViewItem = listView2.Items.Add(label1.Text);

     Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(panel3.Size.Width, panel3.Size.Height);
     panel3.Refresh();
     panel3.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel3.Size.Width, panel3.Size.Height));

     imageList1.Images.Add("1", bm);
     listViewItem.ImageKey = "1";           
}
```

Comment: want to display the duplicate image of the panel in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a variable to determine the name every time you add one.

This sample keeps a variable at class level (`nextImageNumber`) which value is raised with 1 every time you generate a bitmap:

```
int nextImageNumber = 1;

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    var listViewItem = listView2.Items.Add(label1.Text);

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(panel3.Size.Width, panel3.Size.Height);
    panel3.Refresh();
    panel3.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel3.Size.Width, panel3.Size.Height));

    string name = nextImageNumber.ToString();
    imageList1.Images.Add(name, bm);
    listViewItem.ImageKey = name;

    nextImageNumber++;           
}
```